# React on object changed in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an `ObservableCollection<Person>` in my viewmodel. This is bound as an `ItemsSource` to a DataGrid in the view. The class Person only has threeProperties:

```
 public class Person : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Guid id;
        public Guid Id
        {
            get { return this.id; }
            set
            {
                this.id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

        private string firstname;
        public string Firstname
        {
            get { return this.firstname; }
            set
            {
                this.firstname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Firstname");
            }
        }

        private string lastname;
        public string Lastname
        {
            get { return this.lastname; }
            set
            {
                this.lastname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Lastname");
            }
        }
    }
```

The class ViewModelBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

The items in the collection are updated perfect if I add or remove an entry in the dategrid. The item is then also removed in the collection.

My problem is that the content of an person-item is updated, but I don't know how I can react on this.

Do I have to add an event or something else to the person-class to get informed or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface on your class `Person` so that any change in Person properties gets reflected back on UI.

Sample -

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private Guid id;
   public Guid Id
   {
      get { return id; }
      private set
      {
         if(id != value)
         {
            id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
         }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
       {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 12 seconds -- +1!

Comment: Yes, that I have now. But I need to be informed (by an event or so) at the moment the edit is done

Comment: @Tomtom - Your person class in not implementing INPC.

Comment: I updated my code. If I debug my application I can see that the items in the collection are updated. But I need to be informed at the moment they are changing. I have to write them to a database

Comment: Not sure what you meant but i guess you want to know about property change before it actually changes. If yes then you should also implement [INotifyPropertyChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging(v=vs.110).aspx). You can hook on that event for prior notification for any property change.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. But how can I react on this in my viewmodel with my code? Do I have to subscribe to this event for each person in the collection?

Comment: Unfortunately yes you have to subscribe for each person in your collection and make sure that on deletion of object, you unhook it to prevent any memory leaks.

Comment: Ok. That means that my person-class needs an event where I can subscirbe on. And in the viewmodel I have to add an eventhandler for each item in the collection. That's sad.